# MVUE using Lehmann Scheffe theorem

Tags: statistics

[image]

Trying to solve the task from above, I'm having trouble with solving the last part. My idea was to find both $E[-Y_1]$ and $E[\frac{Y_n}{2}]$ and show, that both are equal to $\frac{n}{n+1}\theta$. The answers provided by the book say, that $\frac{n+1}{n} \hat\theta$ is the MVUE of $\theta$.
My calculations lead me to completely another answer, I'm wondering if there is a typo in the book, or if my calculations are bad. Tried to find mistake, but couldn't. Or maybe the method is completely wrong for some reason, that I don't see?

For those brave enough, to go through my calculations, [here](https://goo.gl/photos/WcxUPes59uCQRNnb8) they are.

Thanks in advance for all Your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3627187/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody, that would have simmilar problem. You need to get the distribution of $\hat\theta$ and then get expected value based on that.